# Write regex for matching all 4 digit numbers between patterns

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to find pattern in string. Its gonna have a word 'LAT_LON' then some non word characters and then many 4 digit numbers and after then some alphabet or end of string.

```
Eg1. 

SOME EXAMPLE STRING 12334...
LAT_LON .... 1234 5678 9012 1234 
1234 1234 

Eg2.
SOME EXAMPLE STRING 1234...
LAT_LON ... 1234   5678 9012 1234 
1234 1234 SOMETHING_ELSE
```

In both the examples I need those 6 4-digit numbers after the pattern 'LAT_LON' and before any other alphabet.

EDIT: I am working in python, although I don't care much about the language. I am fairly new to regex world. So I am just trying some random stuff, nothing very conclusive at all till now.

Comment: Edited the problem with the required information.

Comment: Show your attempt and we'll help you by telling where you got it wrong. (It isn't that hard and so I bet someone posts a "use this: xxx" within *minutes*. You can use that but you won't have learned anything.)

Comment: @Jongware I completely agree with your comment. It's just this was a very small part of my project and I was very new to this, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: "It's just this was a very small part of my project and I was very new to this, that's why I posted this question." - that doesn't give license to ask other people to do your work for you! You said you are trying, so you should include those efforts in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to capture the numbers then split on whitespace.
`LAT_LON[^\da-zA-Z]*(\d{4}(?:\s+\d{4})*)`

Then split capture group 1 on whitespace.

```
 LAT_LON [^\da-zA-Z]* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d{4} 
      (?:
           \s+ 
           \d{4} 
      )*
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Here is a more verbose formatted version.
( *Regex's constructed by [RegexFormat 6](http://www.regexformat.com)* )

```
 LAT_LON                # Exact 'LAT_LON'

 [^\da-zA-Z]*           # Optinal chars, 0 to many times
                        # not digit nor letter (case insensitive)

 (                      # (1 start), Capture all 4 digit numbers
      \d{4}                  # Single 4 digit number

      (?:                    # Cluster group
           \s+                    # Whitespace(s)
           \d{4}                  # Single 4 digit number
      )*                     # End Cluster, do 0 to many times
 )                      # (1 end)
```

Comment: Maybe try to explain the regex parts a bit more for the OP to fully understand? Anyway, you deserve a +1 for the clear multi-line notation of your regex!

Comment: Ok, added more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try it another way, just to have some variation in the answers. I'm going to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for the job.

```
awk '/LAT_LON/,/\n[^0-9]/{printf gensub(/[^0-9 ]/, "", "g", $0) " "}' /path/to/intput/file
```

With a possible pipe to clean up the output `| tr -s ' '`.

This code just searches for lines containing `LAT_LON`, then it will parse each of those lines until a non number is found. On these lines we filter out non spaces or numbers using the `gensub`.

**Note** that the regex is fairly simple because we have filtered out all irrelevant parts. A simple non-numerical removal does the job here. See also [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) if you want to mess around with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), in my opinion it's the best way to learn. In particular [egrep](/questions/tagged/egrep), which supports an enhanced regex language!